# Is there anyway to implement optional command line arguments in Scala?

Tags: scala, command-line, option-type

I want to implement command lines in my program so that they can be optional but as of now the only way I can get my program to run is if I input 3 arguments when I run the program in the command line. Is there any way to have it so I only have to input a minimum of one argument and have the other 2 as optional?

Here is the start of my code:

```
 import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
 import util.control.Breaks._
 object part3 {
   var newStartTime = 0
   var newEndTime = 0
   var csvStartTime = 0
   var csvEndTime = 0
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     var csV = args(0)
     var daY = args(1)
     var time1 = args(2)
     var time2 = args(3)
     newEndTime = checkLengths(time1, time2)
     val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile(csV)
     var z = new ListBuffer[String]()
     var z2 = new ListBuffer[String]()
     var i = 0
```

Updated code:

```
val fileName = args(0)
courseCode1 = args(1)
val courseCode2: Option[String] = Try(args(2)).toOption
val courseCode3: Option[String] = Try(args(3)).toOption

val extraCourseSelection = for {
    c2 <- courseCode2
    c3 <- courseCode3
}
courseCodeFixed1 = courseCode1.toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0)
if(c2!=null)
{
    courseCodeFixed2 = c2.toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0)
}
if(c3!=null)
{
    courseCodeFixed3 = c3.toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0)
}
print(courseCodeFixed2)
print(courseCodeFixed3)
```

I tried implementing this solution but now it does not want to read any of my command line arguments at all

Comment: Your code has too much information (why show us the variables `z`, `z2`, and `i`?), not enough information (what's the default value for `daY`?), and confusing information (you say you want 1 minimum and 2 optional arguments but you code requires 4 arguments). It also doesn't compile. Code posted to SO should be [minimal, complete, and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val fileName    = args(0)
val courseCode1 = args(1).toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0)
val courseCode2 = args.lift(2).map(_.toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0))
val courseCode3 = args.lift(3).map(_.toUpperCase.patch(4, " ", 0))
```

You can add `.getOrElse()` to provide a default value if you don't want `Option[String]` results.

Comment: There ya go I'm new to this stackoverflow thing lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scala.util.Try` to catch the index out of bounds exception and use `toOption` to convert `Try[_]` to `Option[_]`:

```
import scala.util.Try

...

val csV: Option[String] = Try(args(0)).toOption
val daY: Option[String] = Try(args(1)).toOption
val time1: Option[String] = Try(args(2)).toOption
val time2: Option[String] = Try(args(3)).toOption
```

Then to use the optional values you can use a for comprehension:

```
val newEndTime = for {
  t1 <- time1
  t2 <- time2
} yield checkLengths(t1, t2)
```

Comment: `Try` with `.toOption` is overkill. Just use `lift`: `args.lift(0)`

Comment: I tried implementing this solution but when I pass arguments now the program just doesn't read them at all?(including the first argument) Please see my updated code above